# How can I acquire python test coverage matrix

Tags: python, testing, code-coverage, django-testing, coverage.py

I want to make a matrix that looks like the following
[image: test coverage matrix]

Currently I'm trying to acquire the above matrix for Django test cases. However, coverage.py(the coverage tool that I'm using) doesn't seem to support such feature of acquiring test coverage matrix. Is there any other way?

Comment: The matrix seems kind of vague to me.  Does "cost of ticking things off" mean, "how long it takes to run those tests"? I don't understand "Things to tick off"? You don't run separate tests to find the statement coverage vs. the branch coverage.  You'll need to explain more about what this matrix means, and maybe what you will do with the information.

Comment: Sorry for the vague explanation.  "cost of ticking things off" does mean, "how long it takes to run those tests". "Things to tick off" could be either branches or just lines that were covered in the test. I wanted to make this matrix because I wanted to do test suite minimization for django and I first need to find out which tests cover which part. I figured out that there are no features in coverage.py and I created my own program that can generate test coverage matrix. The project is located at (https://github.com/gnsrla12/python_test_coverage_matrix)